# Is it bad practice to store a user object with hashed password in Vuex store.state

Tags: vuex

Is safe to do so or should I only store not sensitive data in the $store ?
Is there another clever way to access user data without exposing the password ?

```
const actions = {
          getUserArticles: ({ commit }) => {
            axios.get('/userArticles').then( ({data : data }) => {
                commit('GET_USER_ARTICLES', data.articles);
                        if (data.articles) {
                            commit('LOGIN_USER', data.user);
                        }
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
          }
    }

const mutations =  {
        LOGIN_USER: (sate, user) => {
            state.user = user;
            state.userLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The user object your API return should not contain the password. Just make it return keys that you want like username, email, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was just being lazy !